# Remove HTML from post title whilst decoding HTML Entities in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following example of what a user might type into a field for a post name:

`<h1><span>They're awesome people</span></h1>`

Now because this is a post title I want to remove all that HTML completely before saving it to the database. This is because for a) security reasons and b) if I export this as JSON I don't want to be cleaning up HTML on output for 3rd party users.

I have tried the following in my model:

```
public function beforeSave() {

        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['title']))
        {
            //$this->data[$this->alias]['title'] = Sanitize::clean($this->data[$this->alias]['title'], array('encode'=>true,'remove_html'=>true));

            $this->data[$this->alias]['title'] = html_entity_decode(Sanitize::html($this->data[$this->alias]['title'], array('remove'=>true)));
        }
        return true;

    }
```

As you can see I have tried both Clean and HTML from the Sanitize class to clean out the HTML but both cause a problem in that they escape the quote from `they're` making it like `&#039;`. I have tried using the `html_entity_decode` around the sanitize to clean this up but it still happens. Any ideas on how to do this?

If I do this though:

```
echo html_entity_decode('They&#039;re awesome people');
```

it works fine so the function is fine, it's a problem with using it in conjunction with the sanitize class in CakePHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use

```
 Sanitize::paranoid()
```

[Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html)

Or even [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

To make Sanitize::html work

```
Sanitize::html($var, array('remove'=>true, 'quotes' => ENT_NOQUOTES));
```

it uses htmlentities internaly and default flag is set to ENT_QUOTES.

Comment: strip_tags does the trick! But why does the CakePHP version butcher your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You should try [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode) function.

**Edit:**

Using only PHP function instead CakePHP library, you can try [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags).

Comment: Well `html_entity_decode` works fine when doing it in a PHP page but doesn't work when wrapping the sanitize so the function is fine just not when using it in the beforeSave around the clean. **And that doesn't work either just tried it.**

Comment: Now I tested with CakePHP, you're right. Well, not a CakePHP solution, but can you use just a PHP function? You can use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) for remove HTML.